# ADF augmented dickey fuller test Distribution

Tags: augmented-dickey-fuller

In [this link](http://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/stochastic-processes/dickey-fuller-test/) It is said that "We can use the usual linear regression approach, except that when the null hypothesis holds the t coefficient doesn’t follow a normal distribution and so we can’t use the usual t test. Instead, this coefficient follows a tau distribution, and so our test consists of determining whether the tau statistic τ (which is equivalent to the usual t statistic) is less than τcrit based on a table of critical tau statistics values shown in Dickey-Fuller Table."

My question is although at the beginning of paragraph it is said we can not use usual t test, at the bottom it is said test consists of determining whether the tau statistic τ (which is equivalent to the usual t statistic).? Could you help me overcome that contradiction?

Comment: Is there anyone who can reply my question? maybe @Richard Hardy?

Comment: I have been waiting for a week still I can not get response. Could you be more sensitive to return to question?

Comment: I deem I have asked a explicit, understandable and significant question. Why anyone returns to me?